# How can I get My.stepwise.glm to return the model outside the console?

Tags: r, glm

I asked this question on RCommunity but haven't had anyone bite... so I'm here!

My current project involves me predicting whether some trees will survive given future climate change scenarios. Against better judgement (like using Maxent) I've decided to pursue this with a GLM, which requires presence and absence data. Everytime I generate my absence data (as I was only given presence data) using randomPoints from dismo, the resulting GLM model has different significant variables. I found a package called My.stepwise that has a My.stepwise.glm function (here: My.stepwise.glm: Stepwise Variable Selection Procedure for Generalized Linear... in My.stepwise: Stepwise Variable Selection Procedures for Regression Analysis) , and this goes through a forward/backward selection process to find the best variables and returns a model ready for you.

My problem is that I don't want to run My.stepwise.glm just once and use the model it spits out for me. I'd like to run it roughly 100 times with different pseudo-absence data and see which variables it returns, then take the most frequent variables and move forward with building my model using those. The issue is that the My.stepwise.glm function ends by 'print(summary(initial.model))' and I would like to be able to access the output similar to how step() returns a list, where you can then say 'step$coefficients' and have the function coefficients return as numerics. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you use `MASS::stepAIC()`  instead ???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.